# Value comparison query Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

Good afternoon! I need to make a comparative query. I implemented this snippet in my view, but it returns me an error:

> TypeError at /listsalocate/
>   QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): 40.

Here is my code:

Models

```
class Room (models.Model):
    block = models.ForeignKey (Block, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    room = models.CharField ('Room:', unique = True, max_length = 50)
    capmax = models.IntegerField ('Maximum Cap:')
    available = models.BooleanField ('Available', default = True)
    busy = models.BooleanField ('Busy', default = False)
    internet = models.BooleanField ('Internet', default = False)
    projector = models.BooleanField ('Projector', default = True)
    computer = models.BooleanField ('Computer', default = False)


class  Estclass (models.Model):
    estclass = models.CharField ('Class', max_length = 20)
    course = models.CharField ('Course', null = False, max_length = 50)
    period = models.CharField ('Period', null = False, max_length = 50)
    discipline = models.CharField ('Discipline', max_length = 50)
    estudents = models.IntegerField ('Qty')
    professor = models.CharField ('Professor', max_length = 50)
    allocated = models.BooleanField ('Allocated', default = False)
    internet = models.BooleanField ('Internet', default = False)
    projector = models.BooleanField ('Projector', default = False)
    computer = models.BooleanField ('Computer', default = False)


class Allocate (models.Model):
    date = models.DateField ('Date', auto_now = True, blank = True)
    days = [
        ('Monday', 'Monday'),
        ('Tuesday', 'Tuesday'),
        ('Wednesday', 'Wednesday'),
        ('Thursday', 'Thursday'),
        ('Friday', 'Friday'),
        ('Saturday', 'Saturday'),
    ]
    day = models.CharField ('Day', max_length = 11, choices = days,
    default = 'Confirming')
    time = models.ForeignKey (Time, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    estclass = models.ForeignKey (Class, on_delete = models.SET ())
    room = models.ForeignKey (Room, on_delete = models.SET ())
```

excerpt from my view with method

```
...
    room = Allocate.objects.select_related ('room'). values (room = room.capmax)
    capmax = int (room)
    estclass = Allocate.objects.select_related ('estclass'). values (estclass = estclass.estudents)
    capmax = int (estclass)

    if estclass > room:
        messages.info (request, 'Number of students greater than capacity')
        return redirect ('allocate: listalocate')
...
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) instead of `values`. And looks like you need to read more about QuerySet. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#making-queries)

Comment: thanks for your advice friend ..
... I couldn't find what I want ... I'm inexperienced with django

Comment: What are you trying to do with "room = Allocate.objects.select_related ('room'). values (room = room.capmax)" ? The expression in values seems to be wrong and and should be the culprit here. I would say same for second similar query.

Comment: Good afternoon friend ... I'm trying to allocate a class, I need to know if the number of students is less than the capacity of the room. Understood? can you help me???